# WPF DataGrids for hierarchical information

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that contains an `ObservableCollection<Foo>`, and `Foo` in turn contains an `ObservableCollection<Bar>`. I would like a pair of datagrids, one showing the collection of `Foo` objects in the application and the other showing the collection of `Bar` objects in the `Foo` that's currently selected in the first datagrid (and I want to be able to add, update and delete entries in both datagrids).

So far I've got the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="5" Background="Gray" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar Name" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Test
{
    public class Foo
    {
        static int _nextId;
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
        public Foo()
        {
            Id = _nextId++;
            Name = String.Empty;
            Bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
        }
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        static int _nextId;
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Bar()
        {
            Id = _nextId++;
            Name = String.Empty;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
            Foo newFoo;
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
            {
                newFoo = new Foo();
                newFoo.Name = String.Format("Foo {0}", index);
                Foos.Add(newFoo);
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I've not bound the 2nd DataGrid yet, because I've not got the faintest idea how to do it! All the examples I can find assume I'm binding DataTables, not custom objects, and bind to a relation on the DataTables. I don't really understand binding all that well yet. Can anybody tell me how to bind the 2nd table?

(And yes, if you've seen my other recent questions, I am giving WPF another shot after not getting on well with it in the early days).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If you want editable grids first of all you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged like

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel 
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Foos = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static int _nextId;
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public Foo()
    {
        Id = _nextId++;
        Name = String.Empty;
        Bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Notify("Name");
        }
    }

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}

public class Bar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static int _nextId;
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Bar()
    {
        Id = _nextId++;
        Name = String.Empty;
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Notify("Name");
        }
    }

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In xaml Binding for first Grid is corrrect and for second grid you can set ItemsSource as the the selectedItem of First grid using ElementName

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=gridTop, Path=SelectedItem.Bars}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bar Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="False"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. ElementName is clearly another binding type I need to learn about.

I note that you have broken out a separate ViewModel class. Is that just for architectural tidiness or it it necessary?

Comment: Thats MVVM lol. That is Design pattern best suited for WPF/Silverlight Application .

Comment: Thanks again. I recognised it as MVVM. In fact, in the real program I'm experimenting with I had separated out the model but it's pretty small so I'd not put a view model in-between (I need to understand binding and commands *much* better before I try that!) but I flattened the architecture for the example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use Binding to Element
Name the top grid gridTop

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=gridTop, Path=SelectedItem.Bars}"
```